# File Upload for ChatGPT API like data analysis on web (not fine-tuning)

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api

How would I upload files to the ChatGPT API (similar to the "data analysis" on the web interface)? Is this possible? The only [upload](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/files/create) I could find in the API was for fine-tuning.